# Opacity issues in Chrome and IE

Tags: css, cross-browser, opacity

I am seeing weird behavior in IE 7 and Chrome with changing the opacity on a transparent background png in my navigation.

the CSS :

```
 ul.tabs a {
    height: 48px;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80);
    -moz-opacity:0.8;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity: 0.8;
    }

 div.header ul.tabs a:hover {  
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    -moz-opacity:1;
    -khtml-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
    }
```

Comment: You may wish to link to the images in question that you are using in case its a format related issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the reason why the rendering looks bad in IE7 is because IE7 doesn't handle opacity well.  Rick Strahl noticed the problem in a blog post titled [Internet Explorer 7.0 and Opacity: Not even close!](http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/7223.aspx)

One comment to that blog post linked to an IE Blog post [Notes on the interaction of ClearType with DXTransforms in IE7](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2006/08/31/730887.aspx) where we learn that the IE Team is aware of the problem and offers an "explanation" that includes this gem:

> "As our users also noticed, the ClearType text then looks extremely blurry - unfortunately these two technologies just don’t mix well.  This is because the basic convolution transform used by DXTransforms does not take into account the spatial nature of ClearType."

I believe the IE Team was able to incorporate ClearType spatial convolution transform accountability into IE8 but, alas, this did not make it into IE7.

Comment: Meh.. another day.. another reason I despise IE.  I ended up just doing CSS image rollovers.. thanks for the response.